# Finding exact number of a given symbol at the beginning of a string

Tags: ruby

I'm trying to solve a Ruby problem using as less code as possible :). I want to check if a given string starts with a varying number of symbols, lets say between one and three 'a'. That's easy using reg exp, I can write string.match(\^a{1,3}.*\). But then I have to make changes on the string depending of the exact number of a's. How can I detect them without using three if's like that:

```
do_string_manipulation1 if string.match(/^a.*/)
do_string_manupulation2 if string.match(/^aa.*/)
...
```

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use a modified version of the first regexp and then simply count the a's it returns? A la

```
m = string.match(/^(a{1,3})/)
case m[1].size
  when 1
  when 2
  when 3
end
```

Of course you can also use an array to store routines to call, depending on the number:

```
routines = [nil, method(:do_string_manipulation1), method(:do_string_manipulation2), ...]
routines[m[1].size].call
```

Comment: A MatchData object, as described here: http://rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.3/MatchData

Comment: Alternatively, you can use the =~ operator and then access the global variable $1 (in this case. Generally it is $1..$n). The benefit of that is that it is faster as it doesn't have to create a MatchData object.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what your string manipulations are.

You can determine the number of consecutive a's by doing:

```
string.match(/^(a{1,3}).*/)[1].size
```

You haven't defined the rules, so mine are:

```
"a"   - downcase
"aa"  - reverse
"aaa" - swapcase
```

So my code is:

```
string.send([:downcase, :reverse, :swapcase][string.match(/^(a{1,3}).*/)[1].size-1])
```

If your rules are more complicated, then you can define them as methods on a class and call them depending on the number returned.